# CakePHP: is there a way to convert snake case column names to camel case before sending the JSON response?

Tags: cakephp

I am using a PostgreSQL database where the column names are in snake case, but want them converted to camel case before sending the JSON response. Is this possible in CakePHP?

I tried aliases in select but this breaks the associated records fetching.

For example. My current response is:

```json
[
  {
    "article_id": 1,
    "author_id": 1,
    ...
  }
]
```

I would like it to be:

```json
[
  {
    "articleId": 1,
    "authorId": 1,
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: You can loop over all string data (in this case keys) in there before it is being returned/outputted, e.g. using a Formatter/Transformer or alike.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mark. I was wondering if there is something at Entity level. For example, Yii 2.0 has the fields() method. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#fields()-detail

Comment: I wouldnt mix this into entity directly. I would use a Transformer in between to decouple internal vs external needs cleary.
Inside your app you dont need this, only for the external json response
See https://fractal.thephpleague.com/ for ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for sth like
https://fractal.thephpleague.com/
A transformer layer between data collecting and data rendering.

Look at this plugin:
https://github.com/andrej-griniuk/cakephp-fractal-transformer-view
If it is not maintained (I didnt check), you can always fork and maintain that one yourself.

Comment: Fractal looks very powerful. I will give it a try. Thank you @mark